# Crystal Report get sum error

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

I watched video tutorial about Crystal Reports. I am confused because when I click *Insert* > *Summary* the `Sum`, `Average` and etc. are not on the list of `Calculate this summary`
[image: Here's the screen shot]
I tried to search web but no luck. Please help me fixing this.

Comment: In-built Sum, Average etc. are the summaries that can be applied only to numeric columns. It seems `Total` field in `receipt_table1` is NOT numeric, it is a text type column storing values as strings. If you do not want to change database then you may try using custom formula fields where you can convert `Total` to numeric and then calculate your summary.

Answer (score 0):

That would be because Crystal sees this field as a STRING and can't sum a string. You can write a formula field that will convert a string to a numeric and then do a summary of the formula:

Val ({YourTable.total})

Answer (score 0):

@Icebergman_NewProgrammer, Your **Sum** field is a nvarcha/nchar or others.

plz check this and insure this int/decimal/numeric etc.